# How to order URLs in Django? I am getting `Page Not Found` error because of misplaced urls?

Tags: python, django

I am getting below error when I want to add a project or go to `project_create` URL.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/project/add/
Raised by:  projects.views.project_detail_view
```

the URL says `/project/add/` that according to the view it must open `project_create_view` but the error is raised by detail view `projects.views.project_detail_view`.

This is the URL:

```
path('project/<slug:project_slug>/delete/',
     project_delete_view, name='project_delete'),
path('project/<slug:project_slug>/update/',
     project_update_view, name='project_update'),
path('project/<slug:project_slug>/',
     project_detail_view, name='project_detail'),
path('projects/list/', all_projects_view, name='all_projects'),
path('project/add/', project_create_view, name='project_create'),
path('administration/', administration, name='administration'),
path("", home, name='home'),
```

if I comment  this line `path('project/<slug:project_slug>/',project_detail_view, name='project_detail'),` then `project_create` URL goes to right view and right template. Why is this happening? I used different `name`, `url` and `view` name. Why is this happening?

Edit: I added both views

```
@login_required
def project_create_view(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise PermissionDenied

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.instance.title
            form.save()
            project = get_object_or_404(Project, title=title)
            messages.success(request, 'Project created successfully.')
            return redirect(project.get_absolute_url())

    form = ProjectForm()

    return render(request, 'projects/project_create.html', {'form': form})


def project_detail_view(request, project_slug):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=project_slug)
    session_key = 'project_views{}'.format(project.slug)
    if not request.session.get(session_key, False):
        Project.objects.filter(id=project.pk).update(
            visit_count=F('visit_count') + 1
        )
        request.session[session_key] = True

    context = {
        'project': project
    }

    return render(request, 'projects/project_detail.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic URLs must be on the bottom of the list,

```
urlpatterns = [
                  # Fixed URLs
                  path("", home, name='home'),
                  path('administration/', administration, name='administration'),
                  path('project/add/', project_create_view, name='project_create'),
                  path('projects/list/', all_projects_view, name='all_projects'),
    
                  # Dynamic URLs
                  path('project/<slug:project_slug>/',
                       project_detail_view, name='project_detail'),
                  path('project/<slug:project_slug>/delete/',
                       project_delete_view, name='project_delete'),
                  path('project/<slug:project_slug>/update/',
                       project_update_view, name='project_update'),

              ]
```

Ref: [Django URL routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example)

Comment: Thank you I didn't know this

Answer (score 0):

You can order it by app, or by path, for example if you have more than one that starts with `project` you may group them in a different url pattern list.

```
projecturls =[
    # your project path urls
]

urlpatterns =[
    path('project/', include(projecturls)),
    # ...
]
```